# Exchange 2010 Search-Mailbox to delete Exchange Journal emails

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell

I am using this PowerShell command to try and delete emails from our Exchange Journal,

`[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Search-Mailbox -Identity exchangejournal -SearchQuery "Received:12/31/2012..06/30/2013" -DeleteContent`

It says it is successful, but it shows ResultItemsCount: 0 and ResultItemsSize: 0 B <0 bytes>.  But if I log into that mailbox there are emails from that date.  Any suggestions as to what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I'll offer a complete guess - check your date format.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible caveats here.

Enclose the Keyword Query in curly brackets:

```
Search-Mailbox -Identity exchangejournal -SearchQuery {received:12/31/2012..06/30/2013}
```

Make sure your dates matches the ShortDate format on your computer. For example on my machine with Danish locale setting it would be: `{received:31-12-2012..30-06-20}`. An easy experiment to determine yours would be:

```
(Get-Date).ToShortDateString()
```

---

I've seen problems querying the `Received` property in the past. If none of the above helps, you might want to try with the `Sent` property instead:

```
Search-Mailbox -Identity exchangejournal -SearchQuery {sent:12/31/2012..06/30/2013}
```

If you get any syntax errors regarding the dates after removing the quotations marks, enclose the date range in parentheses: `{sent:(12/31/2012..06/30/2013)}`